# Is Nirvana's 'Aero Zeppelin' intro in Locrian mode?

Tags: theory, scales, modes, analysis

The song 'Aero Zeppelin' by Nirvana (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtT7YCh9aeI) for Youtube video link) begins with a calmer introduction that has a 'creepy' feeling, due to the occurrence of the tritone. I have tried to analyse the mode the song is in, and I think it is in D# Locrian based on the notes I can hear (all the notes seem to fit in the Locrian D# scale). But I am not familiar enough in music theory to be sure whether that is correct. I was looking for examples of songs that used the Locrian mode and I thought this could be a possible candidate.

So is this part of the song really in Locrian, and if not, what mode is it in?

Comment: Be careful how Locrian (or any other mode) is labelled. D# Locrian is a different set of notes from the Locrian of D#. So in fact, Locrian D# is confusing! D# Locrian uses the notes from the E major key, whereas the Locrian *of* D# uses those from Cx. Confusing? A little...

Comment: most songs are not "in" modes.  Unless you're talking about 500 year old church music or folk music played on instruments that don't have a full chromatic scale, you'll rarely find music that is "in" one specific mode in the way you mean here, that's not the way 99% of western music works; we use *all* the notes to create different musical effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in Eb (D# will do, but Eb is easier to work in!), probably due to down-tuning to Eb. The 'odd' note is b5, as used in Blues. So, rather than being modal, it just incorporates a blue note - that note in question being Bbb or A natural. I'd put it in Eb blues.